# TTL for Hbase Tables works on Column Qualifier and does not delete updated Columns

Tags: hbase, ttl

Why TTL forHbase Tables works on Column Qualifier and does not delete the complete row if some Qualifier are updated later. It deletes only the Column Qualifier that is beyond TTL. 
Is this the desired behavior, How to get the complete row deleted for such case ?

Answer (score 0):

If you define **TTL** on **`columnfamily`** level while creating table

`(or)`

By using **`alter`** command, then we are able to **delete entire row** from HBase.

**`Example:`**

**`1. Creating table with TTL:`**

```
hbase(main):> create 'ttl_tbl', {'NAME' => 'cf','TTL' => 20} //all rows will expire after 20 secs
hbase(main):> put 'ttl_tbl','row1','cf:desc', 'TTL shu'
hbase(main):> put 'ttl_tbl','row1','cf:desc1', 'TTL shu'
hbase(main):> scan 'ttl_tbl'
ROW                                                    COLUMN+CELL
 row1                                                  column=cf:desc, timestamp=1562101913869, value=TTL shu
 row1                                                  column=cf:desc1, timestamp=1562101914445, value=TTL shu
```

**`After 20 secs:`**

```
hbase(main):009:0> scan 'ttl_tbl'
ROW                                                    COLUMN+CELL
0 row(s)
```

**`2. Creating table without TTL:`**

```
hbase(main):010:0> create 'ttl_tbl1','cf'
hbase(main):011:0> put 'ttl_tbl1','row1','cf:desc','TTL shu',{TTL => 10000} //this row will be deleted after 10 sec as TTL on qualifier is in milliseconds

hbase(main):012:0> put 'ttl_tbl','row1','cf:desc1', 'TTL shu' //no ttl will not be deleted.
```

Comment: How to achieve the same via Java API?

Comment: if I update row1, will its ttl be updated?